# How do I kill every entity except arrows and players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a world where arrows, if shot at a player, will destroy items, but keep the player alive.

However when I use the command `/kill @e[type=!Player]`, the arrows will be destroyed.

Comment: What game are you talking about? You should add more information to your question, otherwise no one will be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first:

```
/scoreboard objectives add noKill dummy
```

Run these on a clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @e noKill 1
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Player] noKill 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow] noKill 0
```

Now kill all entities with a noKill score that is not 0:

```
/kill @e[score_noKill_min = 1]
```

Comment if this doesn't work, but it works for me.

Comment: really thx,it works :)

Comment: wait it did work but now not anymore hmmm :/